# Convergence of quadratic form $y^T Q y$ where $y$ is a random iid sequence of length $n$ and $Q$ is an $n \times n$ random matrix independent of $y$

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, limits-and-convergence, measure-concentration

For each positive integer, let $Q_n=(q_{i,j})_{i,j \in [n]}$ be a random $n \times n$ psd matrix.  In the limit $n \to \infty$, suppose the eigenvalues of this sequence of matrices are uniformly bounded in the following sense

- $\lambda_{\max}(Q_n) = \mathcal O_{\mathbb P}(1)$.

Let $y_1,\ldots,y_n,\ldots$ be a sequence of iid Gaussian or Rademacher random variables (independent of the $Q_n$'s) such that $\mathbb E y_1 = 0$, $\mathbb E[y_1^2] = 1$. Define $r_n := y^\top Q_n y = \sum_{i=1}^n y_i y_j q_{i,j}$, a quadratic form in $(y_1,\ldots,y_n)$ with coefficient matrix $Q_n$.

> **Question 1.** Is it true that $r_n - \mathbb E[r_n] \to 0$ almost-surely (or in any other reasonable sense) ?

---

### Update (positive answer to a slightly different question)

The answer below establishes that the answer to **Question 1** is No in general.

It turns out that one can answer a slightly different question in the affirmative, namely we show that

> ***Claim.*** *$n^{-1}y^\top Q_n y - n^{-1}trace(Q_n) \to 0$ a.s,*

under the assumption that

- $\sup_n \|Q_n\|_{op} = \mathcal O(1)$, this is a deterministic bound, unlike the probabilistic bound in the previous question.
- $\mathbb E[y_1] = 0$, $\mathbb E|y_1|^2 = 1$ and $\mathbb E|y_1|^{4+\eta} < \infty$, for some $\eta>0$. Note that these conditions are satisfied by Gaussian and Rademacher random variables considered in the original setting.

The above claim appears as Lemma 7.6 of [this manuscript](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.03003.pdf).

So the argument goes like this ...

> ***(Lemma B.26 of [Bai and silverstein 2010](http://ndl.ethernet.edu.et/bitstream/123456789/60805/1/140.pdf)).*** *For any $p \ge 2$, it holds that*
> $$
> \mathbb E_y[|y^\top Q_n y - trace(Q_n)|^p] \le 2K_ptrace(Q_n^2)^{p/2}(\nu_4+\nu_{2p}).
> $$
> where $\nu_k := \mathbb E|y_1|^k$.

Now, since $\|Q_n\|_{op} \le C$ uniformly over $n$, then from the above we get
$$
\mathbb E_y[|n^{-1}y^\top Q_n y - n^{-1}trace(Q_n)|^p] \le 2C^2 K_p\nu_{2p}n^{-p/2}
$$

Thus, by Markov's inequality
$$
\mathbb P(|n^{-1}y^\top Q_n y - n^{-1}trace(Q_n)|^p| > t) \le \frac{2C^2K_p\nu_{2p}}{tn^{-p/2}}.
$$
If $p=2+\eta/2$ (and this is the crucial ingredient), we have $\nu_{2p} < \infty$ by hypothesis and so the RHS is $\mathcal O(n^{-p/2})$ and therefore summable. Thus Borel-Cantelli gives $n^{-1}y^\top Q_n y - n^{-1}trace(Q_n) \to 0$ a.s. $\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\Box$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\ep}{\varepsilon}\newcommand{\la}{\lambda}$
We inteprete the abuse of notation "$r_n \to \mathbb E[r_n]$" as "$r_n - \mathbb E[r_n] \to 0$".

One may ask instead whether
\begin{equation*}
    \rho_n:=\frac{r_n}{Er_n}
\end{equation*}
converges to $1$ in probability, say. The answer to this question is: usually, no.

Indeed, let
\begin{equation*}
    Q_n=(2+\ep)I_n,
\end{equation*}
where $\ep$ is a Rademacher random variable independent of the $y_i$'s and $I_n$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix.
Then $1\le\la_{\min}(Q_n)\le\la_{\max}(Q_n)\le3$,
\begin{equation*}
    Er_n=\sum_{i,j}Eq_{ij}\,Ey_iy_j=\sum_{i}Eq_{ii}=2n,
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
    Er_n^2&=\sum_{i,j,k,l}Eq_{ij}q_{kl}\,Ey_iy_jy_ky_l
    =\sum_{i,k}Eq_{ii}q_{kk}=n^2\,Eq_{11}^2=5n^2. 
\end{aligned}
\tag{1}
\end{equation*}
So, $Var\,r_n=n^2$ and hence
\begin{equation*}
E(\rho_n-1)^2=  Var\,\rho_n=1\not\to0. \tag{2}
\end{equation*}

So, $\rho_n\not\to1$ in $L^2$.

Moreover, similarly to (1) we get $Er_n^4=O(n^4)$ and hence $E\rho_n^4=O(1)$. So, if we had $\rho_n\to1$ in probability, then by the uniform integrability we would get $E(\rho_n-1)^2\to0$, which would contradict (2). Thus, $\rho_n\not\to1$ in probability.

Comment: Concerning your first sentence, my $r_n$ is missing a $n^{-1}$ factor. A typo.

Comment: Also $a_n \to b_n$ should be read as $|a_n - b_n| \to 0$.

Comment: @dohmatob : Anyhow, we do not have $r_n-Er_n\to0$. Since $Er_n=2n$ and $r_n/Er_n\not\to1$, we do not even have $r_n-Er_n=o(n)$.

Comment: Thanks for the input (upvoted). But, one has $n^{-1} r_n - n^{-1}\mbox{trace}(Q_n) \to 0$ (say, a.s), right ?

Comment: It would be easier for us to converse if you restored the original definition of $r_n$ and fixed the question.

Comment: Restored and fixed. Hope that helps.

Comment: Since $Er_n=E\,trace(Q_n)$ and $r_n-Er_n$ is not $o(n)$, it follows that  $n^{−1}r_n-n^{-1}E\,trace(Qn)\not\to0$.

Comment: Please see update the question. It looks like using higher-moment information gets almost sure convergence. Am I missing something here ?

Comment: @dohmatob : In your initial post, you had the conjecture that "$r_n\to\mathbb E[r_n]$". Even if that conjecture is interpreted as $(r_n-\mathbb E[r_n])/n\to0$ (as suggested in your first two comments), the counterexample given in the answer disproves that as well. Now you have changed your question again, thus finally invalidating the answer (which would now change from negative to positive).

Comment: I've modified the question to better reflect the situation: (1) negative answer to original question, (2) positive answer to "slightly" different question. I hope this does better justice to your post.

Comment: So, is there a question left at all here?

Comment: Nope. Answer accepted! Thanks again! Since you ask, I wonder if the the condition $\sup_n \|Q_n\|_{op} \le C < \infty$ condition (in the $n^{-1} y^\top Q_n y - n^{-1}trace(Q_n) \to 0$ claim which I stated and proved) can be replaced by something like $\mathbb P(\|Q_n\|_{op} > C) \le c_n$ for some $(c_n)_n \in \ell^q$, with $q$ large enough ? Of course, I could make this into a separate question.

Comment: @dohmatob : Indeed, I think additional questions should be asked in separate posts.

Comment: Please see follow up question here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/404773/under-what-conditions-on-the-random-matrices-q-n-do-we-have-n-1y-n-top-q